# How Do I Set My Spinner Layout Appropriately?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, spinner

See the screenshot below. For the first two fields I just used ArrayAdapaters (int and String). For the third, I created a custom adapter (and custom Spinner Object) so that I could show a hint. All is working well except the formatting looks bad. The dropdown items are smaller and not padded like the others. Also the line beneath "Credit" is higher than for the other spinners. This line adjusts to where it should be after I select a value.

Where do I go to fix the formatting? The height and width settings match the other spinners in the XML. I'm relatively new to this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In you custom spinner adapter you should have:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(yourSelectedItemLayout, parent,false);
    TextView make = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Make);
    v.setText(data.get(position));
    return row;
}


public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(yourDropDownlayoutOut, parent,false);
    TextView make = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Make);
    v.setText(data.get(position));
    return row;
}
```

yourSelectedItemLayout and yourDropDownlayoutOut would be layouts you create where you can set your own formatting.